# Properties of combination

Tags: combinations

I need help understanding why
$ \left(  \frac{n}{m} \right) ^k {{m}\choose {k}} \leq {{n}\choose {k}} $. Here m divides n, and k is a fixed small constant. 
I have tried expanding both sides, but not getting anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality can be rewritten as
$$\frac mm\frac{m-1}m\cdots\frac{m-k+1}m\leq\frac nn\frac{n-1}n\cdots\frac{n-k+1}n.$$
Can you show that every factor on the left side is smaller then or equal to its corresponding factor on the right side?

Comment: I wasn't looking at it the right way, thanks a lot!